# Cross platform secure socket connection

Tags: java, objective-c, security, sockets

I am new to network programming and recently learnt how to create a Java ServerSocket and connect, read and write to it though Objective-C streams.

I now would like to be able to encrypt the connection but have no experience with this.

Looking at other code samples, it looks quite complicated with no explanation of what each step does, meaning I cannot port to java or to Obj-C, or understand it for myself..

Would it be better to generate a public/private key in java and encrypt data with the public key in Objective-C? Or could someone please walk me through the secure sockets setup(secure server in java and then connecting/reading/writing in objective c)?

Many thanks!

Comment: copy here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601898/cross-platform-real-time-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether you use some HTTP-based service or your own protocol, use SSL/TLS. It's widely understood and available in high-quality libraries. Cryptography is *hard*; don't roll your own. You can use either `openssl` or `keytool` to generate the necessary server-side keys for Java.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've been looking at this but have no idea where to start.. Do you have a link to a tutorial or implementation? (Preferably Java for server and Obj-C for client)

Comment: @LlamaGoingNorth Just Googling for "Java SSL" brought up a number of good articles, including [http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-security-tutorial-%E2%80%93-step], [https://sites.google.com/site/ssljavaguide/], and [http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php].